# How can I return a grpc::ClientContext from a function?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, grpc

I am trying to avoid repetitive code by having a function for creating ClientContexts. The following code compiles:

```
template<typename T>
grpc::ClientContext&& context_with_deadline(T duration) {
    grpc::ClientContext context;
    auto deadline = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + duration;
    context.set_deadline(deadline);
    return std::move(context);
}
```

It does not compile without making the return type an rvalue reference, or without the explicit std::move (I am using C++ 11 so I believe RVO and copy ellision is not guaranteed).

In some other scope, I'm now trying to do this, which does not compile:

```
grpc::ClientContext stream_context = context_with_deadline(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));
```

It tries create a temporary object and copy it into `stream_context`, which cannot be done because the copy constructor of `ClientContext` is private (not deleted).

Is there any way to do this without using `unique_ptr`? If not, could this be considered a bug? (it seems the copy constructor should be deleted, not private).

Note: when I say "does not compile", it means the following was emitted by the compiler:

> error: ‘grpc::ClientContext::ClientContext(const grpc::ClientContext&)’ is private within this context

Comment: Can you elaborate "does not compile"?

Comment: Okay, but if it's movable, can you declare function as returning `grpc::ClientContext`, but end it with `return std::move(context);`? Named RVO is not a requirement, so you need to give compiler a hint.

Comment: @bipll declaring the function return type as `ClientContext` instead of `ClientContext&&` means the function does not compile. I guess RVO is still not a requirement, even with the std::move hint.

Comment: How exactly does it not compile? Okay, then `return ClientContext(std::move(context));`

Comment: @bipll Won't compile. Try [this simple sample code](https://onlinegdb.com/HknV6C7Fm). The code will compile when you add a public move constructor, make the copy constructor public, or remove the private copy constructor. But as it is, moving that type is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. The issue can be worked around with `std::unique_ptr` until the following is done:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16680

Answer (score 2):

The copy constructor is private, and no user defined move constructor exists, so what you are trying to do is not possible. Instead of returning a new instance from the method, make it take a reference to an instance:

```
template<typename T>
void context_with_deadline(grpc::ClientContext& context, T duration) {
    auto deadline = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + duration;
    context.set_deadline(deadline);
}
```

and then call it like so:

```
grpc::ClientContext stream_context;
context_with_deadline(stream_context, std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));
```

Comment: I am trying to use the move constructor, not the copy constructor. Why does doing a move require a public copy constructor?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `=` will trigger a move assignment in certain cases (copy ellision). The question is how can I move the function return value into a local variable, and if it's not possible, could it be considered a bug in `ClientContext`. I have also tried to call the move constructor like `ClientContext context(rvalue_reference)` but that doesn't work either - it still wants to resolve the function call to the private copy constructor.

Comment: I have updated my answer. There is no move constructor. std::move is just a cast.

Comment: shouldn't the compiler have generated a move constructor? And also, does this constitute a bug in the class? It seems very restrictive to not be able to return it from a function.

Comment: If it's a bug depends on the author's intentions. Maybe they don't want that type to be movable. I can't give any insight to that.

Comment: No, the compiler doesn't generate a move constructor when a user-defined copy constructor is present, which is the case here.